# How do I add adapter tests in ember-data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit

I'm trying to create an adapter for ember-data, but I'm finding the testing framework that's used incomprehensible.

In the same directory as `rest_adapter_test.js`, I've created my own `websocket_adapter_test.js`.

When I run the rack server included `bundle exec backup config.ru`, and go to localhost:9292/index.html?package=ember-data it runs all the existing tests, but not the new one.

Is this something specific to `qunit.js`? Or does it have something to do with `minispade.js`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple checkout of [emberjs/data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) and a `rackup` as suggested in the README didn't work for me either.

Using the instructions from [embers/ember.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js) on the other side worked for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/emberjs/data.git
cd data
```

I then created the new test file, and afterwards

```
gem install bundler
bundle
bundle exec rackup
```

and now the test is run when accessing http://localhost:9292/tests/index.html?package=ember-data

But I don't know if this is intended behavior ...

UPDATE: the **Unit Tests** section in the **README** has been [updated](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/c5270a9cf013537372bbda3d94f4ea9c46ef41f3): it's suggested to use `bundle exec rackup`